# How to do line by line debugging in Code::Blocks IDE?

Tags: c++, gcc, ide, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks IDE which is open source IDE providing multiple languages.
It is using GCC compiler.

I want to do line by line debugging of program.
Have you any about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "Step Into" command in the "Debug" menu which should start debugging and stop at the first line. Then continue through using the "Next Line" command (also in the "Debug" menu).

If that doesn't work as intended, you can set a breakpoint (by clicking in the left 'gutter', or 'margin') at the first line of your app, and start the debugger from the "Debug" menu, and then use the "Next Line" command in the "Debug" menu.

The shortcut keys vary based on your settings but should be listed alongside the menu command, and makes 'step'ping easier.

---

Since you're using gcc to compile, you can specify the `-g` parameter to include debugging symbols, and invoke `gdb` from the a command shell with the compiled binary as an argument: `gdb <yourapp>`. 
(If [n]curses is installed, specify `-tui` for a more pleasing interface: `gdb -tui <yourapp>`.

Once in gdb, the command `start` will start debugging and stop automatically at `main()`. You can then step thru with the `step` command, and `quit` to exit.

You can always `man gdb`...

Comment: Thank you for answer
But it works up to the declaration and doesn't enter in to the main function and user defined functions.

Answer (score 0):

GCC's optimization sometimes makes debugging not easy. To improve your debugging experience, make sure you set optimization to off or to a low level via [`-O0` or `-O1`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options).

Additionally, make sure you have all debug information included in the binary: [`-g3`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options).

Answer (score 0):

Please go through these steps below:

1. At first click on debug Menu bar : (Debug-> Debugging windows-> Watches). Now your debugging window is on and the window will be shown at the left corner.
2. Add breakpoint just clicking left portion of the mouse at those lines you want to debug or test.
3. Again click on  (Debug-> start/continue) It will show a console window. Put input on it. Now press Enter button.
4. Click on  (Debug-> Next line) or press F7 for line by line debugging.

Happpy Coding !